# Different windows explorer icon/grouping domain user vs local user

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, taskbar, icons

I recently rebuilt my laptop because I needed to go up to a larger HDD.

I reloaded all software from home under a local user. Then I fired up my vpn software and joined the domain from home. But I couldn't initiate a logon of the domain account until I got into the office.

When opening windows explorer directories on the local user the standard folder icon which is pinned to the taskbar shows up. But when I do the same thing on my domain profile account it uses a completely separate windows explorer icon.

I took ownership of a folder on my local user account and opened the folder under the domain profile. Then I opened any random folder under the domain profile. This allowed me to take a screengrab of the two icons side by side. I labeled which was which using snipping tool and my touchpad (which is why it is so squiggly).

[Here's that screengrab so you can see what i'm talking about.](http://1drv.ms/1jMvrqN)

How can I resolve this issue? I've rebuilt countless machines in this same manner and never had this weird issue. It doesn't affect my usage of the machine but it's a little annoying and i'd like to figure out how to fix it. I've tried to search it out on my own before posting here but I must not be using the correct phrases in my searches to find anything.

Comment: your image link is not working btw.    Just curious, why would you join a domain over VPN?   do you usually join machines to the domain over VPN?  Please re post a screenshot so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: No issues viewing image from the first link but here's an alternate for those who are having issues http://imageshack.com/a/img801/9720/nolz.png

Comment: Joining the domain from home over vpn shouldn't have any effect here. I was snowed in and wanted to get it out of the way. Done it before on other win7 machines and they didn't have this issue with the user profile. I could treat this like a corrupt user profile and make myself a new one but I figured I could take an opportunity to learn and fix the actual issue instead of doing something as drastic as a new user profile.